# Failure to get live USB 22.04 to boot

Tags: boot, usb

I am running dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows, with Ubuntu 14 in a separate partition. The computer has an Intel Core i3-4170 CPU.
I downloaded the Ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso and have created two "bootable" USBs, one using the Startup Disc Creator which I had on my system, and a different one which I downloaded today.
Neither of these two works, even holding down f12, esc or "return". A boot USB I made some time ago for Ubuntu 18.04 works fine.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: To boot the USB install, you use the UEFI one time boot key, not esc or shift. That often is F12 but varies by vendor, check manual. Some tools that create live installer, may make it UEFI only or BIOS only, although ISO is configured for UEFI or the very old BIOS boot mode. Try a different installer. How large is flash drive. Ubuntu ISO now is larger. If older system you may want Kubuntu or an lightweight install that uses less resources. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I use Kubuntu on both new & old systems.